# Processing format is blank after request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I make a post request Rails seems to be having trouble processing the format I want to respond to.

#### Form

```
    <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: users_pre_otp_path(resource_name), method: :post, remote: true, html: { id: "step-1" }) do |f| %>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :email, "Username" %>
        <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
      </div>

      <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit "Next", class: "actions__button button button--primary" %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
```

#### Routes

```
  devise_scope :user do
    scope :users, as: :users do
      post "pre_otp", to: "users/sessions#pre_otp"
    end
  end
```

#### Error

```
Processing by Users::SessionsController#pre_otp as
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "user"=>{"email"=>"fa@slm.com"}, "commit"=>"Next"}
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["email", "fa@slm.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 8ms (ActiveRecord: 1.5ms)



ActionController::UnknownFormat (ActionController::UnknownFormat):

app/controllers/users/sessions_controller.rb:6:in `pre_otp'
```

As you can see. the `Processing by Users::SessionsController#pre_otp as` is blank. How can this be?

When I check the `request.format`:

`#<Mime::NullType:0x00007fbf00d42ad0>`

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to process the form as ajax?

if not, try removing "remote: true" from the form-tag